# Finding the length of a terminal session

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

I'm attempting to create my own bash script to output the length of the current terminal session, as well as do various other things with said length.

The problem I'm running into, is that in the script...

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSIONLENGTH=$(echo $SECONDS)
echo $SESSIONLENGTH
```

...another instance of bash shell (or at least I believe this is what is happening) is created, in which it's own `$SECONDS` value is being assigned to `$SESSIONLENGTH` rather than the `$SECONDS` value of the shell that is running the script.

So my question, how do I return the length of the current session inside of a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
source /path/to/script
```

or

```
. /path/to/script
```

To run the commands in the script in the current `bash` session.  Note: do not call `exit` from the script in that case since it will finish your current session (likely before you can see the time if the terminal emulator closes on shell exit).

On the other hand, if you are only measuring session time you could also do:

```
time bash
```

And once you exit that `bash` session the time you have spent in it will be printed.  That is portable across several shells (not only `bash` and `zsh`, which have `$SECONDS`).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to automatically run a script inside the current session like this, or is there no way around typing `source` every time?

Comment: @TrevorSears - Well '.' is the short version for `source` and it is a lot faster to type.  If your script is in the PATH, then you can simply do `. script.sh`.  That's a lot less typing.  If you want to make is even shorter you could use an alias, e.g. `alias sc=". script.sh"`, and then you only need to type `sc`.

Comment: I guess what I was asking was, if I was trying to have a script that was reliant on being run through `source` or `.` be able to be distributed without having to have each user create an alias, or run the script with `source` or `.`, would that be possible?

Comment: @TrevorSears - Not that I am aware of.  But asking a user to `source`/`.` a script instead of plainly running it is not uncommon.  The big example of an application that asks a user to `source` an activation script is python's `virtualenv`, and that is a very popular piece of software.  You can also create the `alias` inside the script and tell the user that after `source`ing your script he can use the aliased command (that is actually something that python's `virtualenv` does too)